# Find common alphabets in multiple dictionaries - python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm making the code returning character with given strings.
I know it is easier to use when using the counter function but I'm trying not to use it.

here is my code

```
class Solution:
    def commonChars(self, A):
        dic = {}
        for i in range(len(A)):
            A[i] = list(A[i])
            dic[i] = self.checkLetter(A[i])
        print(dic)
        
    def checkLetter(self, Letter_list) : 
        letter_cnt = {}
        for l in Letter_list:
            if l in letter_cnt : letter_cnt[l] += 1
            else : letter_cnt[l] = 1
        return letter_cnt
```

I've done making a letter counter with a dictionary but I have no clue what to do next. could you give me a hint?

```
# given input_1 : ["bella","label","roller"]
# expected output is e,l,l because it is common in every string in the given list
>>> ["e","l","l"]

# result of my code
>>> {0: {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2}, 1: {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2}, 2: {'r': 2, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}}

# given input_2 : ["cool","lock","cook"]
# expected output
>>> ["c","o"]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Ns68, can you explain your expected output, why is ``e`` there because ``l`` is duplicated in 2nd & 3rd but ``e`` is not.

Comment: @Sushanth my mistake, I was testing different input but forgot to change.

Comment: @Ns68, still why ``l`` is duplicated not ``e``  ?

Comment: 'e', 'l', and 'l' is present in each of the strings.

Comment: 'l' is present twice in each of the strings.

Comment: @Sushanth It is right SagarAdhikari explained. I think you confused by my mistaken input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible solution with `reduce`.only add one line:

```
from functools import reduce


class Solution:
    def commonChars(self, A):
        dic = {}
        for i in range(len(A)):
            A[i] = list(A[i])
            dic[i] = self.checkLetter(A[i])
        print([char for char, count in reduce(lambda x, y:{k:min(x[k], y[k]) for k,v in x.items() if y.get(k)}, dic.values()).items() for _ in range(count)])

    def checkLetter(self, Letter_list):
        letter_cnt = {}
        for l in Letter_list:
            if l in letter_cnt:
                letter_cnt[l] += 1
            else:
                letter_cnt[l] = 1
        return letter_cnt


s = Solution()
s.commonChars(["bella","label","roller"])
# ['e', 'l', 'l']
s.commonChars(["cool","lock","cook"])
# ['c', 'o']
```

Split it:

```
result_dict = reduce(lambda x, y:{k:min(x[k], y[k]) for k,v in x.items() if y.get(k)}, dic.values())

print([char for char, count in result_dict.items() for _ in range(count)])
```